# Clarification - can I connect an .net app with odp.net 12c to an Oracle 19c database?

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, odac

Tried connecting to oracle 19c db from an .net app. Server has 12c ODAC (ODP.net)installed. It worked seamlessly, just wondering will it create future issue?

1. wondering is odp.net designed to work with lower & higher DB versions or it won't?
2. Please suggest is nuget odp.net dll or ODAC install is best. Will nuget odp.dll override server odac installation?

Comment: Have a look at this matrix: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1

Comment: Thanks much @WernfriedDomscheit !  Just new to Oracle, so when they say Oracle client, nuget dll (oracle.manageddataacess.dll )  also  called as client ?  will it overwrite the odac installation?

Comment: It just a single DLL. Installing several versions should be handled like any other multi-version .NET assemblies. Installing more than one unmanaged ODP.NET will be tricky.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/what-is-oracle-database-compatibility.html#GUID-1146B7A7-81EE-4F90-8A0A-8440A6618CD9

Comment: Lack of research. There is plenty of this info